# What is this string resolving to if it is not empty/null?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows Vista 64 bit. I have some Scrapy code that is submitting a series of date stamped XHR requests in sequential order. On dates where there are results returned I get my desired output printed without issue.

On days where there is no data I want the code to print "No fixtures today: date" (with date being a date variable. However nothing is being printed if the elif condition is not met.

I have tried using "!= ''" and "== ''" instead, but I get the same results. I can only assume this is because the string I am evaluating is not resolving to empty/null on days where there is no data returned. The code is here:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta as td
from ast import literal_eval
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import time
import re

d1 = date(2013,11,01)
d2 = date(2014,5,31)

delta = d2 - d1


for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    time1 =  str(d1 + td(days=i))
    time2 = time1.split("-", 1)[0]
    time3 = time1.split("-", -1)[1]
    time4 = time1.rsplit("-", 1)[-1]

    time2 = int(time2)
    time3 = int(time3)
    time4 = int(time4)

    date = datetime(year=time2, month=time3, day=time4)


    url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/tournamentsfeed/8273/Fixtures/'

    params = {'d': date.strftime('%Y%m%d'), 'isAggregate': 'false'}
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36'}

    response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

    try:
        fixtures = literal_eval(response.content)
        fixtures = str(fixtures)

        if fixtures is not None:

            fixtures = re.sub("\[", '', fixtures)
            fixtures = re.sub("\], ", ',\n', fixtures)
            fixtures = re.sub("\'", '', fixtures)
            fixtures = re.sub("\]", '', fixtures)

            print fixtures 
            time.sleep(1)

        elif fixtures is None:

           print "No Fixtures Today: " + date
           time.sleep(1) 

    except SyntaxError:

        pass
        time.sleep(1)
```

Can someone please tell me whether:

1) The code really is resolving to something other than empty/null

2) The syntax I need to point this code to whatever the variable 'fixtures' does resolve to if there is no data returned for that day.

Thanks

**

### EDIT:

**

Re comments section below, if the except: statement is removed, the code returns this error, which I am told is because it is parsing HTML rather than the syntax being actually invalid:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\newtets\newtets\spiders\test3.py", line 32, in <module>
    fixtures = literal_eval(response.content)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(expr, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

As this has now become a blocker to my original question being answered, I must now also ask:

1) Why is a syntax error being thrown up in this instance
2) What is an alternative method of coding this?

Comment: At the very least, you do: `if fixtures is not None: ... elif fixtures is not None: ...` and `str(something)` will just about never be `None`.

Comment: `except SyntaxError: pass` -- Never ever do this.  Ever.  You must fix this before we can attempt to answer your question.

Comment: @sharth sorry, that was a typo. fixed now.

Comment: @user3045351, because it could mask a serious problem with the code.  I put the question to you: *why did you put it there*?

Comment: @BrianCain because i was getting html on some pages that was causing an error. i am happy from the output and the simple nature of the code i haven that i wont get any other types of error generated.

Comment: @BrianCain - i think its for the literal_eval. My suggestion would be to put the except right after the eval.

Comment: You misunderstand the term `SyntaxError`.  The unqualified type `SyntaxError` refers exclusively to errors in the python program you have written, itself!  There are very very few good reasons to ever catch this error.  And making `pass` its exception handler is a cardinal sin.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SyntaxError

Comment: @user3045351 SyntaxError means a problem with how the code is written, to the point where the code is no longer valid code. It points to an error in your code, not in anything you're getting.

Comment: ok, well that is a separate issue to the one in the question. can you suggest an alternative for that first and i will look at this other issue afterwards? thanks

Comment: @user3045351, no you must do it in this sequence.

Comment: @BrianCain see edited question above.

Comment: @user3045351: So you're running `literal_eval` on something that isn't python code?

Comment: can you add else there and just print whatever you get with some debug string attached so you don't miss it and then let us know what output you're getting if there are no fixtures, also i doubt you will ever get None from the str() call you do

Answer (score 2):

`from ast import literal_eval`

This module is designed to give you introspection capability on the Abstract Syntax Tree for python code.

> The ast module helps Python applications to process trees of the Python abstract syntax grammar. The abstract syntax itself might change with each Python release; this module helps to find out programmatically what the current grammar looks like.

[`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
>       expression.  The string or node provided may only consist of the following
>       Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans,
>       and None.

But you have passed it HTML content you downloaded from a remote server via http!  It is not python source and if you expect it to contain python source you must first unwrap it from whatever containers you'll find there.  Once you do that note that you may have a significant security problem with the code that remains.

---

Here is a mechanism which will mitigate the problem you experience.  You should probably take a look at the content in `response.content` and consider parsing it instead (perhaps some combination of `re.search`/`split`/`int()` or `float()` and `list()`).

```
try:
    fixtures = literal_eval(response.content)
    handle_fixtures(fixtures)
    time.sleep(1)
except SyntaxError:
    # unfortunately using this method it's impossible to 
    # distinguish "no data" from "invalid data"
    print "No Fixtures Today: " + date
    time.sleep(1)

def handle_fixtures(fixtures):
    fixtures = str(fixtures)

    if fixtures is not None:

        fixtures = re.sub("\[", '', fixtures)
        fixtures = re.sub("\], ", ',\n', fixtures)
        fixtures = re.sub("\'", '', fixtures)
        fixtures = re.sub("\]", '', fixtures)

        print fixtures
```

Comment: part of the answer I got for an earlier question I asked on how to obtain this data for a single date was as follows: "Note that the response is not a json, but a basically a dump of Python's list of lists, you can load it with ast.literal_eval():

Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python expression. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None." the link to the original question and the full answer is here:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268476/what-is-this-string-resolving-to-if-it-is-not-empty-null?noredirect=1#comment39373972_25268476

Comment: for most pages returned the above works fine, however on some it throws up the error listed above because there is also some html on the page.

Comment: That was bad advice IMO but if you must handle `SyntaxError` you should keep the window extremely narrow.

Comment: ok, how can I narrow the window? also, can you see what the strings that look like they are null actually are? thanks.

Comment: I have moved the function above the try: statement as I assume this is where it is meant to go. this code runs without error, however I'm not sure how this is any different to the code I started with, as (forgive me if I am wrong), all it has done is shunt the string conversion and substitution to a function from the try: statement. also, losing the if/elif means that there is now nothing to handle instances where there is not an error, but where no data is returned for legitimate reasons. i will change the the except: to print the errors rather than pass, however i am still...

Comment: stuck with my original issue. instances where no data is returned is clearly not resolving to null. i can see part of the issue now actually. the regex masks that an empty day of data is printed as '[]', but im not sure how to reference that within an if/elif as 'elif fixtures == []' does not work.